# Extending an ArrayList - fragile-base class

Tags: java, stack, stack-pointer

Examining the best practices in Java, we find avoiding inheritance is a good one. One of the reasons maybe illustrated in the following problem:

Here we have a sub-class "Stack" extends "ArrayList"

```
class Stack extends ArrayList
{   private int stack_pointer = 0;
    public void push( Object article )
    {   add( stack_pointer++, article );
    }
    public Object pop()
    {   return remove( --stack_pointer );
    }
    public void push_many( Object[] articles )
    {   for( int i = 0; i < articles.length; ++i )
            push( articles[i] );
    }
}
```

Let us say we are into adding to a stack using `push()` defined in the previous code, and then we want to clear the stack using `clear()` of the base-class -i.e ArrayList-

```
Stack a_stack = new Stack();
a_stack.push("1");
a_stack.push("2");
a_stack.clear();
```

- Here the problem is

> The code successfully compiles, but since the base class doesn't know
>   anything about the stack pointer, the Stack object is now in an
>   undefined state. The next call to push() puts the new item at index 2
>   (the stack_pointer's current value), so the stack effectively has
>   three elements on it—the bottom two are garbage.

So my questions would be, why

> base class doesn't know anything about the stack pointer

in other words, where is the state of the stack pointer being reserved?

source: [Why extends is evil](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html)

Comment: For your idea, you have to implement the top of the stack. Also, you need to   add some additional items, for example architecture: LIFO, FIFO, etc

Comment: *"The next call to push() puts the new item at index 2"* No, it causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: *"where is the state of the stack pointer being reserved?"* With the object data, same as all the other data that `ArrayList` defines, it's just that `ArrayList` doesn't know about it, only `Stack` does. --- Anyway, your code is flawed, since there is no need for `stack_pointer`, as the list size is the same thing. If you want to use `ArrayList`, then use it right. If you want your own `stack_pointer` (should be named `stackPointer`), then don't use `ArrayList`.

Comment: Mr. @Andreas I was thinking of something else. However, what do you mean by  "it causes an IndexOutOfBoundsException", I do guess it has nothing to do with that, It's just a matter of the updated stack_pointer variable where clear() in this case does not return it back to 0.

Comment: Javadoc of [`add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) says: *"Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())"*. Since index is 2 and size is 0, you get ... **`IndexOutOfBoundsException`**.

Comment: You are totally right. thx. man I forgot we are using add. not normal psuh() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `stack_pointer` is a member of the `Stack` class so how could the `ArrayList` superclass have any idea about it? Since it can't and doesn't the call to `clear()` isn't going to do anything to it.

You need to Override the `clear()` method in your `Stack` class.

Something like

```
@Override
public void clear()
{
   super.clear();
   stack_pointer = 0;
}
```

Then when a user calls `clear()` on a `Stack` it will cause the pointer to be reset.

Also you need to be aware that a user can call the functions `add()`, `insert()` etc on the `Stack` which since they aren't overridden will call the `ArrayList` functions. This is likely not what you want.

A better approach would be to create a `Stack` with an `ArrayList` inside so you can hide the methods you need to hide.

Something like

```
public class Stack
{
    private ArrayList<Object> stack = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private int stack_pointer;

    public void push(Object obj)
    {
       stack.add(stack_pointer++, obj);
    }

    // Other methods

    public void clear()
    {
       stack.clear();
       stack_pointer = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Stack extends ArrayList {

    private int stack_pointer = 0;
    private int stack_mem = 16;
    private ArrayList<Object> mem = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void push(Object article) {
        if (stack_pointer < stack_mem) {
            mem.add(article);
            stack_pointer++;
        }
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (stack_pointer > 0) {
            return mem.remove(stack_pointer--);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void clear() {
        stack_pointer = 0;
        mem.clear();
    }
}
```